# Swift performance on optional UI elements

Tags: swift, uikit, option-type

Setting up a UILabel in Swift I can do the following

```
@IBOutlet var wLabel: UILabel!
```

or

```
@IBOutlet var wLabel: UILabel?
```

Setting the text I can either do

```
wLabel.text = "..."
```

or, for the latter do

```
wLabel?.text = "..." // with a question mark for the optional
```

Keeping them optional will help for the case when they are unexpectedly nil as it will just skip this call then and go ahead with the code. Having them declared with the `!` would crash the app if the label was nil.

Now why would you not make everything optional? The only reason I could think of would be for better performance. Should I stay away from having them optional if my app has a lot of UI elements so them being optional would mean a disadvantage regarding performance? I wasn't able to find any information on this anyhere.

Comment: They are both optional. There is no performance difference.

Comment: *"Keeping them optional will help for the case when they are unexpectedly nil"* - but you want it to crash if it's unexpectedly nil because that is a programming error during development. Preventing the crash doesn't actually fix the problem, it hides it.

Comment: Well I can think of cases where you'd want something to keep running then, without checking for nil. For example 2 interface controllers that work the same way except for a few buttons. You could use the same class for them but you would have to adjust your code accordingly for either class. Using `?` will let you go ahead without any modifications

Comment: Obviously if the component truly is optional, you wouldn't make it an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: Although, it that case it could be reasonable to create two controllers, with the shared code extracted to superclass.

Comment: Marking outlets as optional with the questionmark is in no case a good case I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting something up as an outlet it's set up as a force unwrapped optional (with exclamation mark `!`) because Swift requires your classes to have all of their properties initialized when the object is constructed (i.e. `init` method is called). Outlets are not created during object construction but rather assigned later when the xib or storyboard data is loaded into your component. Force unwrapped optionals are basically a way to say that you guarantee that the property will be initialized after object's `init` is called and before they're used.

There are no performance gains to using either of these. An `Optional?` type means that the property can either be `nil` or have a value. A force unwrapped optional `!` means that the property is guaranteed to have a value when it is used. Upholding this is up to the developer and using such property if its value is `nil` will result in a crash.

Answer (score 2):

## Using ? in your Outlet will make your code untracable

Crashes are very good in some scenarios, because if no crash is there then it becomes super difficult to trace even small error.

**Consider the examples of @IBOutlet with `!`:**

```
@IBOutlet var wLabel: UILabel!
wLabel.isEnabled = true
```

Just remove the connection of your Outlet label from your storyboard and run the app, your app will crash on `wLabel.isEnabled = true`. Since you got a crash so you can got to your storyboard see whether the connection is proper or not. In case there is no connect you add it and damn! you solved the problem easily.

**Now consider the examples of @IBOutlet with `?`:**

```
@IBOutlet var wLabel: UILabel?
wLabel?.isEnabled = true
```

Do the same thing, just remove the connection of your Outlet label from your storyboard and run the app, your app won't crash at all. You won't be able to know the error, hence making your code a mess and untracable.

Apple guys were very aware of optional thing, they did force unwrapping of `@IBOutlet` for a reason. And of course there is no performance difference between `!` and `?`